# Is there way to "Create Test Certificate" by command line for VSTO project on Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: certificate, vsto

Current VSTO (Office addin) project has trusted publisher code signing certificate has set up. It is working on CICD build server.

Individual developer's machine does not have above trusted publisher certificate. So each developer need to to open project file on Visual Studio 2019 and click following "Create Test Certificate..."

I'd like to make remove this manual steps to just clone and build by command line or batch file. Currently MsBuild.exe was used for build. So I'm looking for way to do by command line.

Blank password is OK for dialog after clicked the button ("Create Test Certificate...").

Or any other suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the makecert.exe utility for creating temporary (self-signed) certificates. Read more about this tool in the following articles:

- [How to: Create Temporary Certificates for Use During Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-temporary-certificates-for-use-during-development)
- [How to use makecert.exe to create a self-signed test certificate that can be used with IIS for SSL](http://www.inventec.ch/chdh/notes/14.htm)
- [Creating self signed certificates with makecert.exe for development](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify any certificate to build and run locally. You can simply remove it. Visual Studio will generate a temporary one on build automatically.

Comment: I tried to remove it to make it unspecified or to be blank. But it seems I can only replace different certificate and cannot just remove. Is there way to remove?

Comment: You could remove the auto-generated .pfx file, and the ManifestCertificateThumbprint in the project file. If Visio studio does not fild ManifestCertificateThumbprint, it creates a new one.